# If $f(x) = x^3 - x^2 + (x-1)\sin x$, then which of the following statements is/are true?

Tags: continuity

$f(x) = x^3 - x^2 + (x-1)\sin x$

$fg(x) = f(x) g(x)$

Which of the following is true?

A) If g is continuous at x = 1, then fg is differentiable at x = 1

B) If fg is differentiable at x = 1, then g is continuous at x = 1

C) If g is differentiable at x = 1, then fg is differentiable at x = 1

D) If fg is differentiable at x = 1, then g is differentiable at x = 1.

[image]

The way I solved :

(fg)'(x) = f '(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)

(fg)'(1) = f '(1)g(1) + f(1)g'(1)

(fg)'(1) = (1 + sin1) (g(1))

so for (fg)'(x) to be continuous at x=1, g(x) should be continuous at x=1 and vice versa.

so for (fg)(x) to be differentiable at x=1, g(x) should be continuous at x=1 and vice versa.

This way I get option A,B,C but the answer given is only A,C.

Please help me understand why the reverse is not true?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formulas in your question and replace the image of text by actual text to make it searchable by search engines and accessible to users with screen readers. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: ok I edited the question

Comment: Make sure that all the information you intend to convey using the image is included in the text and then get rid of the image. Make sure that all formula symbols are typeset using MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$f(x) = x^3 - x^2 + (x-1)\sin x = (x-1)(x^2+\sin x)$$ therefore the inequality
$$\lvert f(x) g(x) \vert \le 5\lvert x- 1 \rvert \lvert g(x) \rvert $$ for $\lvert x-1 \rvert \le 1$.

Now if $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} g(x) =0$, the inequality above proves that $fg$ is differentiable at $1$ with the derivative vanishing at that point. This whatever the value of $g(1)$ is. For example, if $g$ is equal to $\lvert x-1 \rvert$ for $x \neq 1$ and $g(1) = 1$, $fg$ is differentiable at $1$. However, $g$ is not continuous at $1$, proving that **B** doesn't hold.